# Using Microsoft Release Management with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, release-management, ms-release-management

Is it possible to use Microsoft's Release Management product (formerly InCycle's InRelease) with Visual Studio Team Services. (Not Team Foundation Server)

I know it's possible to configure an on-premises Team Foundation Build server and point that at Visual Studio Team Services, but I havent' been able to find anything about Release Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported as of now. RM Update 2 will bring the potential to automate the creation of a release while running a Team Services build when the build agent is running on prem (but no real integration between RM and Team Services).

Complete support for Team Services is coming later this year.

Comment: Any timelines for these releases?